# how is it possible to connect my LCD with the class test so that x is displayed?

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt5, lcd

I'm trying to create a GUI that shows machine data taken from a Raspberry.

Unfortunately, I can't get my QT-Desinger surface updated.

So Im trying it now on this "test class" but sadly not successful

That ist was i allready have. Something is missing... but i dont now what

```
x = 0
class Ui_Form(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(400, 300)
        self.lcdNumber = QtWidgets.QLCDNumber(Form)
        self.lcdNumber.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 50, 361, 191))
        self.lcdNumber.setObjectName("lcdNumber")
        self.lcdNumber.display(x)
        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))

    def run(self):
        if __name__ == "__main__":
            app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
            Form = QtWidgets.QWidget()
            ui = Ui_Form()
            ui.setupUi(Form)
            Form.show()
            sys.exit(app.exec_())

class Test(threading.Thread):

    global x
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
    def runs(self):
        while x <= 20:
            print(x)
            x = x + 1
            time.sleep(2)

t = Ui_Form()
t1 = Test()

t.start()
t1.start()
```

the counter shows 0 and the loop dont start at all..

my goal was for the LCD to constantly update itself an schow x 
is that possible ?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For update the value of x, QTimer is the best way when using PyQt, you do not need to use the threading module

```
from PyQt5.Qt import QLCDNumber, QDialog, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout, QApplication,QTimer
import sys

class LCD(QDialog):
    x = 0
    def __init__(self):
        super(LCD, self).__init__()

        self.lcdNumber = QLCDNumber()
        self.pushStart = QPushButton("Start")
        self.pushStart.clicked.connect(self.update)

        vBox = QVBoxLayout()
        vBox.addWidget(self.lcdNumber)
        vBox.addWidget(self.pushStart)

        self.setLayout(vBox)

        self.timer = QTimer()
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.update)

    def update(self):
        self.lcdNumber.display(str(self.x))
        self.x += 1
        self.timer.start(1000)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    lcd = LCD()
    lcd.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: hi, your code works really well thanks a lot for that i will try to transfer the functionality to my main program
how I understand the Qtimer the solution to the problem :)

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.